# c malloc function rollback

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm working on a chip that has two different volatile memory (say RAM0 and RAM1) which the default memory for runtime variables is RAM0. I've moved the heap area (using memory description file) to the RAM1 area in order to utilize that memory.

As I said the runtime variables are still located in RAM0 address space so when I call malloc and free fuctions some changes occur in related variables on RAM0. By the way, the RAM1 address space is also used by other parts of code as temporary memory, so stored values on this memory will be changed by others.

My problem is that after first call of malloc function it seems that some initialization occurs and some values are stored in malloc specific runtime variables and RAM1 area that will not be reset even after calling free function, but if other parts of code change the values on RAM1 the malloc function will fail after calling again because the pointers and runtime values of malloc function are changed in a wrong way.

Is there any way that whole configuration data of malloc mechanism (that after first call of malloc function are set) be reset in a way that it seems no malloc call occured yet? I want to reset whole data related to malloc function before each call of malloc function. How's that possible?

Comment: It looks like a specialized question about this particular chip and/or implementation of libc on that chip. Please provide more information about the chip, the compiler and the C library you are using.

Comment: The question is: why do you use memory allocation at all? Isn\`t the whole memory block available from the start? From the looks of it, the chip you are referring to does not have any MMU to begin with.

Comment: I'm using ucc compiler which is customized for this special chip. I can't provide more information about chip! But my question is that how can I reset all configuration data for malloc function in any ANSI-C based compiler? Is there any function for that to flush that data?

Comment: @hidefromkgb because there are several developers working on different parts of code so we need to manage that area in such way.

Comment: @unwind thanks for your help :)

Comment: Resetting the internal states of heap management is just like freeing any allocated memory. Even if you think that you still have the pointers to that memory... How should any other code consider this memory as allocated when it is not anymore visible to the heap management? How should overwriting be prevented? Probably, I didn't fully get your actual requirement but for me it sounds like that you need two heap managements. I don't have a link at hand but a few years ago I searched and found source code for clever heap management which we needed for our home-brew virtual machine.

Comment: Looking into our source code, I found a note about its origin and the link: [A Memory Allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) I just checked it - it's still available. I remember that I didn't use the most sophisticated approach (I found that time) to lower the effort for implementation, debugging, and maintenance. However, this algorithm is much more clever than a simple list and upto today good enough for our needs.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your point. I wished to find a method that initializes the malloc-free related variables just like there is no execution of them before! But maybe I'm doing a weird heap management that is not really ok.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your point I'll study Memory Allocator mechanism to get more guidance. Thank you :)